# How do I get an under-bracket in xypic?

Tags: xy-pic

Consider this document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[all,frame]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix@R-R{
    19 & 12 & *+[F_\}]{20} \ar@/_1.5pc/[l] \\ \\
    8^2 & 8 & 1
    }
\]
```

It produces this:

[image: rendering of above]

How do I replace the `}` with a `]`?  (If I do the replacement in source code, I get "Xy-pic error: No generic frames yet!.")  Also, if easily possible, how do I change the lengths of the stems on the `]`, to make it a deeper or shallower "half-box"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to rely solely on [`xypic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xypic). You can use `\underbrace` or `\underbracket`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[all,frame]{xy}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix@R-R{
    19 & 12 & *+[F_\}]{20} \ar@/_1.5pc/[l] \\ \\
    8^2 & 8 & 1
    }
\]

\[
\xymatrix@R-R{
    19 & 12 & \mbox{$\underbrace{20}$} \ar@/_1.5pc/[l] \\ \\
    8^2 & 8 & 1
    }
\]

\[
\xymatrix@R-R{
    19 & 12 & \mbox{$\underbracket[.4pt][10pt]{\,20\,}$} \ar@/_1.5pc/[l] \\ \\
    8^2 & 8 & 1
    }
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any good way to move the bracket up, so it looks like the number is "sitting inside" the bracket?

Comment: @JasonGross: Try with `\raisebox{5pt}{$\underbracket[.4pt][10pt]{\,\raisebox{-5pt}[0pt][0pt]{20}\,}$}`